# No client method with the name 'x' found with SignalR

Tags: c#, typescript, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-core-signalr

I have an ASP.NET Boilerplate v3.6.2 project (.NET Core / Angular) in which I need to call a client function from a backend method, so I'm using the [ASP.NET Core SignalR implementation](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/SignalR-AspNetCore-Integration).

I followed the official documentation, so:

**In the backend**

1. In my module, I added the dependency to `AbpAspNetCoreSignalRModule`:

   ```
   [DependsOn(typeof(AbpAspNetCoreSignalRModule))]
   public class MyModule : AbpModule
   ```

   And added [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Abp.AspNetCore.SignalR/3.5.0-preview3) NuGet package to the module's project.
2. Then I extended the `AbpCommonHub` class to take advantage of the built-in implementation of the SignalR Hub, adding a `SendMessage()` method used to send the message:

   ```
   public interface IMySignalRHub :  ITransientDependency
   {
       Task SendMessage(string message);
   }

   public class MySignalRHub: AbpCommonHub, IMySignalRHub {
       protected IHubContext<MySignalRHub> _context;
       protected IOnlineClientManager onlineClientManager;
       protected IClientInfoProvider clientInfoProvider;

       public MySignalRHub(
           IHubContext<MySignalRHub> context, 
           IOnlineClientManager onlineClientManager,
           IClientInfoProvider clientInfoProvider)
       : base(onlineClientManager, clientInfoProvider) {
           AbpSession = NullAbpSession.Instance;
           _context = context;
       }

       public async Task SendMessage(string message) {
           await _context.Clients.All.SendAsync("getMessage", string.Format("User {0}: {1}", AbpSession.UserId, message));
       }
   }
   ```
3. I changed the mapping of the '/signalr' url to `MySignalRHub`:

   ```
   public class Startup {
       public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) {
           [...]
           # if FEATURE_SIGNALR
               app.UseAppBuilder(ConfigureOwinServices);
           # elif FEATURE_SIGNALR_ASPNETCORE
               app.UseSignalR(routes => {
                   routes.MapHub<MySignalRHub>("/signalr");
               });
           # endif
           [...]
       }
   }
   ```
4. Then I use the hub to send a message in a service implementation:

   ```
   public class MyAppService: AsyncCrudAppService<MyEntity, MyDto, int, PagedAndSortedResultRequestDto, MyCreateDto, MyDto>, IMyAppService {

       private readonly IMySignalRHub _hub;

       public MyAppService(IRepository<MyEntity> repository, IMySignalRHub hub) : base(repository) {
           _hub = hub;
       }

       public override Task<MyDto> Create(MyCreateDto input) {
           _hub.SendMessage("test string").Wait();
           [...]
       }
   }
   ```

**In the client**

All the configurations and inclusions are already in place from the original template. When I open the Angular app I can see this console logs:

```
DEBUG: Connected to SignalR server!
DEBUG: Registered to the SignalR server!
```

When I try to call the backend service which sends the message to the client, I get this warning in console:

```
Warning: No client method with the name 'getMessage' found.
```

I tried many solutions found in the [official documentation](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/SignalR-AspNetCore-Integration#your-signalr-code) and on the Internet but none of them worked. I'm not able to define the 'getMessage' handler in the client code.

Some **non-working** examples I tried:

Implementation 1:

```
// This point is reached
abp.event.on('getMessage', userNotification => {
    debugger; // Never reaches this point
});
```

Implementation 2:

```
// This point is reached
abp.event.on('abp.notifications.received', userNotification => {
    debugger; // Never reaches this point
});
```

Implementation 3:

```
// This is taken from the official documentation and triggers the error:
// ERROR TypeError: abp.signalr.startConnection is not a function
abp.signalr.startConnection('/signalr', function (connection) {
    connection.on('getMessage', function (message) {
        console.log('received message: ' + message);
    });
});
```

Have you ever found yourself in this situation? Do you have a simple working example of the handler definition in the Angular client?

## UPDATE

I tried this alternative solution, changing the implementation of the `SignalRAspNetCoreHelper` class (a shared class which is shipped with the base template):

```
export class SignalRAspNetCoreHelper {
    static initSignalR(): void {

        var encryptedAuthToken = new UtilsService().getCookieValue(AppConsts.authorization.encrptedAuthTokenName);

        abp.signalr = {
            autoConnect: true,
            connect: undefined,
            hubs: undefined,
            qs: AppConsts.authorization.encrptedAuthTokenName + "=" + encodeURIComponent(encryptedAuthToken),
            remoteServiceBaseUrl: AppConsts.remoteServiceBaseUrl,
            startConnection: undefined,
            url: '/signalr'
        };

        jQuery.getScript(AppConsts.appBaseUrl + '/assets/abp/abp.signalr-client.js', () => {
            // ADDED THIS
            abp.signalr.startConnection(abp.signalr.url, function (connection) {
                connection.on('getMessage', function (message) { // Register for incoming messages
                    console.log('received message: ' + message);
                });
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Now in the console I can see both the messages:

```
Warning: No client method with the name 'getMessage' found.
SignalRAspNetCoreHelper.ts:22 received message: User 2: asd
```

So it is working, but not fully. Somewhere the 'getMessage' handler is not visible.
What is the proper way to implement the messages handler in Angular with ASP.NET Boilerplate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `autoConnect: false` to start your own connection:

```js
abp.signalr = {
    autoConnect: false,
    // ...
};
```

**Better yet**...

Don't extend `AbpCommonHub`. You'll find that real-time notification stops working and you need to replace `IRealTimeNotifier` because [`SignalRRealTimeNotifier`](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/097dacf2e2217273cb88f46f11df3257807d9572/src/Abp.AspNetCore.SignalR/AspNetCore/SignalR/Notifications/SignalRRealTimeNotifier.cs#L31) uses `AbpCommonHub`.

> Do you have a simple working example of the handler definition in the Angular client?
>
> What is the proper way to implement the messages handler in Angular with ASPNet Boilerplate?

Follow the documentation and create a separate hub.

Answer (score 5):

You should use `Clients.Others.SendAsync` or `Client.AllExcept.SendAsync` instead of `Clients.All.SendAsync`.

`Clients.All.SendAsync` is designed for scenarios where the client wants to send AND receive messages (like a chat room). Hence all connected clients are supposed to implement `connection.on('getMessage',` in order to receive the notifications. If they don't, they raise the warning **No client method with the name 'x'** found when receiving back the notification they just pushed.

In your scenario, I understand you have one kind of client pushing notifications and another kind receiving them (like a GPS device sending positions to a tracking application). In that scenario, using `Clients.Others.SendAsync` or `Client.AllExcept.SendAsync` will ensure pushing clients will not be broadcasted back the notification they (or their kind) just pushed.

Comment: @john. tks for the advice and formatting. Could you point out to me the correct way to propose an answer ? Pointing to the API correcting the problem and explaining why is somehow inapropriate?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same error in my Angular application where I use the package `"@aspnet/signalr": "1.1.4"`.

[image]

The cause of this issue was I wasn't calling the subscribe method after join the channel.

```
public async getWorkSheetById(worksheetId: string): Promise < Worksheet > {
    const worksheet: Worksheet = await this._worksheetService.getWorksheet(worksheetId);
    this.displayWorksheet(worksheet);
    await this._worksheetEventsService.joinWorksheetChannel(this._loadedWorksheet.id);
    return worksheet;
}
```

So, to fix this I called the subscribe method after join `await this.subscribeToSendMethod(this._loadedWorksheet)`)

```
public subscribeToSendMethod(loadedWorksheet: Worksheet): Worksheet {
    let newWorksheet: Worksheet;
    this._hubConnection.on('Send', (groupId: string, payloadType: string, payload: string, senderUserId: string)=> {
        newWorksheet=this._worksheetHandler.handlePayload(payloadType, payload, loadedWorksheet);
        this.displayWorksheet(newWorksheet);
    }
    );
    return newWorksheet;
}
```